# Foreign key with different name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this model relationship: Club has_many Grounds has_many Visits. The primary key of Club is "club_id" with also the field "clubname". In Visit I have "club_home" and "club_away" which both are integer fields storing a "club_id". Instead of showing the "club_id" I want to show the field "clubname" from Club. How can I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Visit < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :club_home, :foreign_key => :club_home, :class_name => "Club"
  belongs_to :club_away, :foreign_key => :club_away, :class_name => "Club"
end
```

**UPD**

```
@visit.club_home.clubname
@visit.club_away.clubname
```